# Weird Javascript IOS 7 Issue

Tags: javascript, ios, ios7

I have a web application which behaves fine on all desktop browsers and mobile devices however since IOS 7 I am encountering a weird issue.

**Example:**

I am setting an object like

```
(function(){
  //CONSTRUCTOR*
  sampleObject= new function(){
    alert("loaded constructor "+ new Date().getTime()); //only outputted once 
    //swfobject dom load event
  }


...//functions and propeties related to sampleObject

})();

//ASSIGNING THE OBJECT
sampleObject = new sampleObject();
alert("finished assigning object "+ new Date().getTime()); //only outputted once
```

**Issue:**

On ios 7 it seems to randomly lose what sampleObject is and instead reverts to what is inside the snippet with constructor*.  So for example, I have been debugging it at intervals where I am calling a public method on my object such as sampleObject.getResource("a");

And the traces are coming back like:

```
sampleObject = [Object] //Correct
sampleObject = [Object]
```

and then randomly it does this:

```
sampleObject = function(){
        //swfobject dom load event
      }
```

Which basically is the code inside the constructor*.

This then causes my code to throw a reference error as the public properties/methods which I am using throughout such as getResource are not defined...

**Things Tried:**

- Code only initiates once (alerts fire once with single Date / random string)
- I Identified where an error was occuring due to this issue, wrapped around a try/catch however although the code is clearly failing it is not going into the catch.
- Tried it on different IOS versions, all fine except IOS 7

*CONSTRUCTOR - not sure if this is classified as a constructor but that is what it seems to me.

**Unfortunately I cannot post my code publicly as it is part of a commercial project and quite extensive....  However any suggestions or has anyone had any similar issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why the problem is happening, but why are you using the same name for the class and the instance? That's just plain confusing.

Comment: Are you really calling new twice like that? The second call isn't supposed to work.

Comment: Its something I have inherited and therefore dont know the underlying reason, however it works and has done for all major browsers and mobile browsers up to now...Hence my confusion

Comment: It should actually throw an "object is not a function" error...

Comment: Thanks for your commments but I am not understanding why it should throw an error, I am assigning a number of objects and properties to the prototype property of sampleObject...  Renaming the constructor variable seems to have resolved the issue but I am still not sure why you guys think it should throw an error and why it works everywhere apart from ios7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments above.  That pointed me in the right direction.

The problem seems to be that IOS 7 seems to randomly loses scope of the javascript object, and because we werent specifically assigning the sampleObject to the window then it wasnt working all the time.

Therefore solution to my problem was simply to change:

//ASSIGNING THE OBJECT
sampleObject = new sampleObject();

to

//ASSIGNING THE OBJECT
window.sampleObject = new sampleObject();